# Variable not getting picked up inside EOF

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I'm trying to run a commands remotely by doing SSH but variable which is defined inside EOF is not getting picked up.

Variable `$BASE_PATH` is not getting called inside another variable which i'm defining by name `FOLDER_NAME` . Mentioned inside script too. 
I couldn't use `EOF` in single quotes (`'EOF'`) because i have to use variable from exiting shell too.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

FILE_NAME=$2
jvm_list=$1

for jvm in `echo $jvm_list`
do

ssh $jvm << EOF
    echo FILE_NAME=${FILE_NAME}
    export BASE_PATH="\${WEB_DOMAIN_HOME}/Server";
    echo BASE_PATH=\${BASE_PATH};            ##Value of BASE_PATH is getting picked up##
    export FOLDER_NAME=\`ls -1d $"{BASE_PATH}"/properties* | grep -i -v old\`  ##Value of BASE_PATH is coming blank here##
    echo $FOLDER_NAME
EOF

done
```

Answer (score 1):

The construct started with `<< EOF` acts like double-quoted string, so dollar signs are special within it, unless escaped.

Here, you escaped the `$`, so the shell eventually started by `ssh` evaluates that variable

```
echo BASE_PATH=\${BASE_PATH};    ##Value of BASE_PATH is getting picked up##
```

Here, you didn't escape it, so the evaluation happens in the outer shell:

```
export FOLDER_NAME=\`ls -1d $"{BASE_PATH}"/properties* ...\`
```

I do also suspect that the quotes there are misplaced. In Bash `$".."` [is a locale-specific translation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation), and it [seems to be the same in `ksh`](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/07/localizing-korn-shell-scripts.html). You probably don't have a translation for that, so the string should come back as is: `{BASE_PATH}`.

Somewhat related to this may be the backticks, since they need to be quoted too. You could use the `$( ... )` form of command substitution, so you'd again, only need to think about the `$`.

I think this may be what you want:

```
ssh "$jvm" << EOF
    export FOLDER_NAME=\$(ls -1d "\${BASE_PATH}"/properties* | grep -i -v old)  
EOF
```

---

Sanity check:

```
$ foo=out; bash <<EOF
> foo=in; echo $foo
> EOF
out

$ foo=out; bash <<EOF
> foo=in; echo \$foo
> EOF
in
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried by putting my code same as you said , but that doesn't worked. Still value of $BASE_PATH inside FOLDER_NAME is coming blank.  
Error :-
ls: 0653-341 The file /properties* does not exist.

Comment: @manavsharma, argh, facepalm, I missed the exact backslash that was supposed to be added there. So, `${var}` gives the value from the outer shell (main script), `\${var}` gives the value from the inner shell (in ssh).